# There are two tags for accessibility

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I have found two tags for accessibility. The normal one, [accessibility](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessibility) and one with wrong spelling: [accesibility](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accesibility).

Can someone delete the last one or merge them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The merge have been performed, and the 3 questions now have the correct spelled tag. https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accesibility

Thanks for letting us know!